# How to minimize Protobuf.NET memory consumption

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I'm serializing large quantities of classes, most of them as references (as I have multiple refernces to the same classes in my data-structures) using Protobuf.NET.

All of the serialized classes are serialized by using ImplicitFirends.AllFields to make sure
everything is dumped.

In my current test case, I have 53 files with a total sum of 500MB.

When I read this data using a Protobuf.NET de-serializer my private bytes / resident memory shoots up to 9GB and STAYS there (i.e. this is not temporary memory released/GC'd after de-serialization).

Another peculiar thing is that if I re-write (re-serialize) all of the data, it still stays at the same size.

Does this x20 blow up in memory make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll run some tests, but it *sounds* like it is the buffer-pool that it keeps around to avoid allocations. In addition to testing, I'll add a "dump the pool" method in the next release (and disable?). In fact, thinking about it: I'll change these to `WeakReference`, so they can be re-used while they exist, but still collected.

You might also find that (as an option on the contract) using "group" encoding for sub-objects and lists makes a big reduction here; length-prefixed is the default (and Google's preferred option), but groups are much more efficient to write, as they can be written direct without any buffering. Let me know if you would like an example of this. Protobuf-net is designed such that switching between them is not a breaking change, but *other* protobuf clients won't be as forgiving, so trickier if ou are using protobuf for interop to other systems.

Comment: I'm not sure this really is the buffer-pool. When I dump the heap I see multiple (i.e. 10,000 and more) instances of classes that should have been in the single digit range. Is there a way to verify tha the AsReference "feature" really works? I have a specific class that is set to be encoded AsReference, and I literally should have EXACTLY one of these, but I seem to have more than 10,000... which leads me to suspect the AsReference feature...

Comment: @damageboy it would certainly be easy to validate from your data - just call ReferenceEquals. If you can show a small example of your scenario, it would help, note that references are only valid during a single graph operation - if you call Deserialize separately 5 times that is still 5 objects, not one. Is that the scenario here? I so, there may be other options (including a core .NET reference-swapping interface I've been meaning to implement for ages, that might allow you to do what you are after).

Comment: I think I'm closing in on the problem... If I have an inheritance scenario, where C derives from B which derives from A... Should ALL of these classes be marked as Reference?

Comment: Hi Marc, My situation appears to be somewhat complicated. Some of the classes that I mark with "AsReference" are indeed sereialized as references and pass a ReferenceEquals test, while other, more complex ones, perhaps the ones with inheritance DO NOT, and are essentially copied... is AsRefernce supported in scenarios concerning SubTypes and inheritance?

Comment: @damageboy it should be, but that is complex. I would have to test.

Comment: @damageboy to clarify - it is something I will look at; do you have a minimal repro, to ensure I am catering for your scenario?